# Limiting distribution of $n^2T_n$ where $T_n$ is the minimum of $n$ independent $\chi^2(1)$-random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1),\;i=1,2,\dots,n$, $T_n=\min\{X_i^2\}$, what is the limiting distribution of $n^2T_n$? I guess central limit theorem doesn't apply here, and definition approach doesn't really work out.

Comment: I'd suggest first working out the c.d.f. of $Y=n^2 T_n$, noting that finding $P(Y>y)$ may be easiest.

Comment: Yeah but I am stuck with that because chisquare doesn't have a closed form distribution function.

Comment: If you carry out my suggestion you'll see that it's not needed.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
P(n^2T_n>y)&=P(T_n>\frac{y}{n^2})\\
           &=\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i^2>\frac{y}{n^2})\\
           &=\prod_{i=1}^n(2P(X_i<-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{n}))\\
           &=(2\Phi(-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{n}))^n\\
           &=(1-\frac{2\phi(0)\sqrt{y}}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n}))^n\end{align*}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(n^2T_n>y)=e^{-2\phi(0)\sqrt{y}}
$$